# I am writing HLA language to determine the input are the same or not the same

Tags: hla

PROGRAM 6: Same
Write an HLA Assembly language program that implements a function which correctly identifies when all four parameters are the same and returns a boolean value in AL (1 when all four values are equal; 0 otherwise). This function should have the following signature:

procedure theSame( w:int16; x:int16; y:int16; z:int16 ); @nodisplay; @noframe;

Shown below is a sample program dialogue.

Feed Me W: 215
Feed Me X: 215
Feed Me Y: 480
Feed Me Z: 91
Not the same.  AL = 0

Feed Me W: 0
Feed Me X: 0
Feed Me Y: 0
Feed Me Z: 0
Same.  AL = 1

Feed Me W: 0
Feed Me X: 221
Feed Me Y: 100
Feed Me Z: 40
Not the same.  AL = 0

**My output are almost correct but when I entered

```
w : 2
x : 2
y : 2
z : 1
"the same" instead of "NOT the same"
```

Please help with any thoughts that I might be missing.**
I am not sure if register push and pop are the issue.

```
 program Same;
    #include ("stdlib.hhf");

static
    iDataValue1 : int16 := 0;
    iDataValue2 : int16 := 0;
    iDataValue3 : int16 := 0;
    iDataValue4 : int16 := 0;
procedure theSame( w : int16; x : int16; y : int16; z : int16); @nodisplay; @noframe;

static
    
    returnAddress : dword;
    temp: int16;
    
begin theSame;
    pop (returnAddress);
    pop (temp);
    pop (z);
    pop (y);
    pop (x);
    pop (w);
    
    push (returnAddress);
    push (BX);
    
  //Perform Subtask
    mov (z, BX);
    cmp (y, BX);                // Compare z & y
    jne ReturnZero;
    
    mov (y, BX);
    cmp (x, BX);                // Compare y & x
    je ReturnOne;
    jmp ReturnZero;
    
    mov (x, BX);
    cmp (w, BX);                // Compare x & w
    je ReturnOne;
    jmp ReturnZero;

ReturnOne:
    mov (1, AL);
    jmp ExitSequence;

ReturnZero:
    mov (0, AL);
    jmp ExitSequence;

ExitSequence:
    pop (BX);
    ret();
    
end theSame;

begin Same;
    stdout.put ("Feed Me W: ");
    stdin.get (iDataValue1);
    stdout.put ("Feed Me X: ");
    stdin.get (iDataValue2);
    stdout.put ("Feed Me Y: ");
    stdin.get (iDataValue3);
    stdout.put ("Feed Me Z: ");
    stdin.get (iDataValue4);
    
    push (iDataValue1);
    push (iDataValue2);
    push (iDataValue3);
    push (iDataValue4);
    
    call theSame;
    
    cmp (AL, 1);
    je NumbersAreSame;
    jmp NumbersAreDifferent;

NumbersAreSame:
    stdout.put ("Same. AL = 1");
    jmp EndProgram;

NumbersAreDifferent:
    stdout.put ("Not the same. AL = 0");
    stdout.newln();
    jmp EndProgram;
EndProgram:

end Same;
```

Answer (score 0):

***ENVIRONMENT***

- HLA (High Level Assembler - HLABE back end, LD linker)
  Version 2.16 build 4463 (prototype)
- Ubuntu 20.10

***SOLUTION***

- Five values are pushed to the stack when calling `theSame()`, those are the `return address`, `w`, `x`, `y`, and `z`. However in the prologue for `theSame()` six values are currently popped off of the stack.

```
begin theSame;
    pop (returnAddress);
    pop (temp);
    pop (z);
    pop (y);
    pop (x);
    pop (w);
```

- The additional `pop (temp);` seen above causes the `temp` variable to store the value passed in for `z`, `z` to store the value passed in for `y`, `y` to store the value passed in for `x`, `x` to store the value passed in for `w`, and `w` to store the next random value on the stack. Removing the `pop (temp);` instruction will result in your example case passing.

```
Feed Me W: 2
Feed Me X: 2
Feed Me Y: 2
Feed Me Z: 1
Not the same. AL = 0
```

- However the following case will still fail due to errors in the comparison logic.

```
Feed Me W: 1
Feed Me X: 2
Feed Me Y: 2
Feed Me Z: 2
Same. AL = 1
```

- In the following code if `z`, `y`, and `x` are equal then the code will jump to `ReturnOne` with out checking the value of `w`. This is corrected by removing the first `je ReturnOne;` and changing the first `jmp ReturnZero;` to `jne ReturnZero;`.

```
mov (z, BX);
cmp (y, BX);                // Compare z & y
jne ReturnZero;
    
mov (y, BX);
cmp (x, BX);                // Compare y & x
je ReturnOne;
jmp ReturnZero;
    
mov (x, BX);
cmp (w, BX);                // Compare x & w
je ReturnOne;
jmp ReturnZero;
```

***EXAMPLE***

```
program Same;
#include("stdlib.hhf");

procedure theSame(w: int16; x: int16; y: int16; z: int16); @nodisplay; @noframe;  
begin theSame;
    pop(EDX);          // Return Address
    pop(z);
    pop(y);
    pop(x);
    pop(w);
    push(EDX);         // Return Address
    mov(z, BX);
    cmp(y, BX);        // Compare z & y
    jne ReturnZero;
    mov(y, BX);
    cmp(x, BX);        // Compare y & x
    jne ReturnZero;
    mov(x, BX);
    cmp(w, BX);        // Compare x & w
    jne ReturnZero;
    mov(1, AL);
    jmp ExitSequence;
    ReturnZero:
        mov(0, AL);
    ExitSequence:
        ret();
end theSame;

begin Same;
    stdout.put("Feed Me W: ");
    stdin.geti16();
    push(AX);
    stdout.put("Feed Me X: ");
    stdin.geti16();
    push(AX);
    stdout.put("Feed Me Y: ");
    stdin.geti16();
    push(AX);
    stdout.put("Feed Me Z: ");
    stdin.geti16();
    push(AX);
    call theSame;
    cmp(AL, 1);
    jne NumbersAreDifferent;
    stdout.put("Same. AL = 1");
    jmp EndProgram;
    NumbersAreDifferent:
        stdout.put("Not the same. AL = 0");
    EndProgram:
end Same;
```